# Weird MarkDown bug - Text not presenting in source is added

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

The bad formatting in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964276/modify-domineering-game-for-java triggers weird rendering in the text (of the preview and the main post). Nothing seems to be out of place in [the raw source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/908d86a1-685a-4979-8840-8ba750246be3/view-source) either.

[Original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14964276/1) of the post.

> [image: Weird bug]